# Is it possible to declare a global variable for an event handler?

Tags: c#, event-handling, global-variables

How and where can the variable **i** below be declared as a global variable?(I get errors when I declare it above the main below MyClass)

```
    class MyClass
    {
     
        public static void Main()
        {
            
    
            mySerialPort.DataReceived += new SerialDataReceivedEventHandler(DataReceivedHandler);
            
    
        }
     
        public static void DataReceivedHandler(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
        {
          int i;
    
         //
         my_method();
        }
    
    private static void my_method(){
    
    //
    
        }

}
```

In my code I want **i** to be stored as global variable for some reason to store the previous value of **i**.

Comment: C# has no _Global Variables_. The best you can do is a public static field, or preferably, a public static property. For example `public static I { get; set; }` as a member of `MyClass`. If you use a non-automatic property (i.e., you wrote your own getter and setter), then you can track old versions of `I`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
class MyClass
{
    public static int i;
    
    public static void Main()
    {
        mySerialPort.DataReceived += new SerialDataReceivedEventHandler(DataReceivedHandler);
    }

    public static void DataReceivedHandler(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
    {
        i = 1;
        //
        my_method();
    }

    private static void my_method()
    {
        i = 2;
    }
}
```

You can refer to the below as to whether the variable should be public or protected. If it is only being referenced within the MyClass class then protected would suffice.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/access-modifiers

Comment: Why does it work when used as "static int i" bun not just "int i" ? It is very mysterious to me I come from C background.

Comment: The `static` keyword in C# is very close to the C++ `static`.  That was based on the C version of `static`, but extended to objects and classes.  You can think of `static` in C# as _having to do with the class as a whole_ as opposed to non-static stuff as _having to do with an instance of the class_.  The VB equivalent of `static` is `Shared` - with the rough meaning that something that is `Shared` is shared between all instances of the class at the class level

Answer (score 0):

Put this within your `MyClass` class:

```
private static int _i = 0;
private static List<int> _previousValuesOfI = new List<int>();

public static int I
{
    get => _i;
    set
    {
        if (_i != value)
        {
            _previousValuesOfI.Add(value);
        }

        _i = value;
    }
}

public static IEnumerable<int> PreviousIValues => _previousValuesOfI;
```

Now, anyone can get the current value of your global `I` through `MyClass.I`.  They can also set the current value of `I` the same way.  But, when they do, you track the previous versions, which are available from the `PreviousIValues` property (with the oldest version first).  If you want to have the oldest version last, consider using `_previousValuesOfI.Insert(0, value);` instead of `_previousValuesOfI.Add(value);`